# Worklight Fix Pack 6.0.0.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have seen that a known problem will be addressed on Fix Pack 6.0.0.2

When will the Fix Pack 6.0.0.2 is expected to be released?

Answer (score 1):

Worklight 6.0 Fix Pack 2 is scheduled for release some time in February.
This question is better suited for your IBM contact rather than on a technical Q&A website...

If you are an IBM business partner or customer you can open a PMR and request an intermittent iFix.

Answer (score 1):

[Announcing: IBM Worklight and IBM Mobile Foundation Version 6.0.0 Fix Pack 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21664096)